# Scrapy xpath - match DIV value then extract if match or write to separate fields

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm struggling with something here using Scrapy as I'm new to it. I'm trying extract each DIV value and store it in a separate column when writing to CSV. Sometimes the structure might change for example some listing might not have Mobile number, or might have a mobile number and not a Phone number and so forth meaning the DIV's won't be present in the DOM.

If I traverse the structure it will give inconsistent results because some DIV's may not be there because the data ins't there. This could mean I'm mapping the wrong data.

This is the data structure:

```
<div id="business_contact_details">

<div class="contact_details">
 <strong>Contact Person:</strong>
 John Doe
</div><br clear="left"/>

<div class="contact_details">
 <img alt="" class="xfort alpha" src="/images/icons/phonenumber.png?f13g7f" title="phone" /> <strong>Phone:</strong>
 02 42223114
</div>

<div class="contact_details">
 <img alt="" class="xfort alpha" src="/images/icons/mobilenumber.png?sss2" title="phone" /> <strong>Mobile:</strong>
 0466156389
</div>
```

I've been able to extract other parts of the DOM like the profile PIC using this approach and works well:

```
response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'lightview')]/@href").extract()
```

I've been trying with this format `response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'contact_field')] /descendant::strong[contains(text(), 'Mobile:')]").extract()` but only get the string not the value.

Logic I'm trying to dev is for example: IF DIV=Mobile THEN extract value. etc. so I can map correct value to column names. If they didn't upload a mobile number then this would be null.

Also, when I run this `response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'contact_details')]/text()").extract()`

In the result I get a lot of: `['\n             ', '\n             John Doe\n           ', '\n             ', ' ', '\n             ', '\n           ', '\n             ', ' ', '\n             ', '\n           ', '\n                   ', '\n\n                   ', '\n           ']`

How do I get rid of that?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share also `HTML` for `div` for which you want to get null? How does `div` without mobile phone looks like

Comment: Sure, the DIV without Mobile will look like: `<div id="business_contact_details">

<div class="contact_details">
 <strong>Contact Person:</strong>
 John Doe
</div><br clear="left"/>

<div class="contact_details">
 <img alt="" class="xfort alpha" src="/images/icons/phonenumber.png?f13g7f" title="phone" /> <strong>Phone:</strong>
 02 42223114
</div>

</div>` The DIV just won't be present

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the phone number I'd use an xpath like this:

```
//img[@title="phone"]/parent::div/text()
```

or to only take a specific phone number

```
//strong[text()="Phone:"]/parent::div/text()
```

In order to create one value without whitespaces for your name extraction:

```
u"".join(line.strip() for line in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'contact_details')]/text()").extract())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get phone number from "Mobile:" `div` than you can try:

```
//div[./strong="Mobile:"]/text()
```

This should return mobile phone number if it's present or return nothing